# ora-06550 error: Expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle-apex

When I input this code:

```
FOR C1 in
(SELECT A.JENIS_SIJIL, A.SECTION1,A.SECTION2,A.SECTION3,B.CAMPUS,B.CAMPUS_LOGO FROM  SIJIL_TEMPLATE A, CAMPUS_MASTER B WHERE A.CAMPUS_KEY = B.CAMPUS_KEY AND A.SIJIL_KEY = :P63_SIJIL_KEY)

LOOP
 :P63_JENIS_SIJIL := C1.JENIS_SIJIL;
 :P63_SECTION1 := C1.SECTION1;
 :P63_SECTION2 := C1.SECTION2;
 :P63_SECTION3 := C1.SECTION3;
 :P63_CAMPUS := C1.CAMPUS;
 :P63_CAMPUS_LOGO := C1.CAMPUS_LOGO;
END LOOP;
```

this error appears:

```
ORA-06550: line 21, column 26: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 21, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I use this same code in another page, and it works fine there.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Where do you enter this code? Condition? Region? Process? There is more code than just this as the error is referencing line 21, yet you only posted 11?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that your cursor contains at least one row? The PLS-00382 generally occurs when you attempt to assing null to a variable, so if your cursor, or one of the cursor objects is null, the assignment will result in an error such as the one you are experiencing.